# How to SELECT MAX SQL

Tags: sql, derby

I have formed the following query in derby to compute all baseball player's slugging percentage...

```
 SELECT p1.nameFirst as "First", 
 p1.nameLast as "Last", 
 (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0) as "SLUGGING" 
FROM Batting b1 join Players p1 on b1.playerID = p1.playerID
WHERE AB >= 400;
```

It produces all batters who had 400 or more at bats and computes their slugging percentage.  My problem is that I need to select only the one player with the maximum slugging percentage.  I tried surrounding the math block with a SELECT MAX, but to no avail.   My desired output is...

Jose    Bautista    0.7426900584795321637426900

Also, is there any way to format that decimal to a set amount of digits?  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `ORDER BY SLUGGING DESC LIMIT 1` to your query and you should get the top result.

Edit:
It seems Derby does not support limiting the number of rows returned. Then the best way is probably to create a subselect with the max slugging result, and join with that to get the playerId to print.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  I ended up finding a workaround for limit.                ORDER BY SLUGGING DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginning to wonder if I'm helping you write something for the MBA or do your computer science homework. :-)

```
SELECT
    p1.nameFirst as "First", 
    p1.nameLast as "Last",
    b.s AS "SLUGGING"
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAX(
            (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0)
        ) AS s
    FROM
        Batting b1
    WHERE
        b1.AB >= 400
) m1
JOIN
    Batting b
        ON 
                m1.s = (b.H + (2 * b.doubles) + (3 * b.triples) + (4 * b.HR)) / (b.AB * 1.0)
JOIN
    Players p1
        ON
            b1.playerID = p1.playerID
WHERE
    b1.AB >= 400
```

OR

*Not sure this is supported

```
SELECT
    TOP 1
    p1.nameFirst as "First"
    , p1.nameLast as "Last"
    , (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0) AS "SLUGGING" 
FROM
    Batting b1
JOIN
    Players p1 on b1.playerID = p1.playerID
WHERE
    b1.AB >= 400
ORDER BY
    (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0) DESC
```

OR

*I think this one will work

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY
            (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0) DESC
    ) as rownum
    , p1.nameFirst as "First"
    , p1.nameLast as "Last"
    , (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0) AS "SLUGGING" 
FROM
    Batting b1
JOIN
    Players p1 on b1.playerID = p1.playerID
WHERE
    b1.AB >= 400
) AS r
WHERE r.rownum = 1
```

Comment: SELECT
        p1.nameFirst as "First", 
        p1.nameLast as "Last",
        m1.s AS "SLUGGING"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            MAX(
                (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0)
            ) AS s
        FROM
            Batting b1
    ) m1
    join
        Batting b
           ON 
                m1.s = (b.H + (2 * b.doubles) + (3 * b.triples) + (4 * b.HR)) / (b.AB * 1.0)
    join
        Players p1
            ON
                b.playerID = p1.playerID
    WHERE
        b.AB >= 400;

Comment: I had to modify your first query a little bit (see above) , but now it is giving me "error: attempted to divide by zero".  It turns out this statement SELECT
        MAX(
            (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0)
        ) AS s is returning empty.  Any ideas why?

Comment: I ended up finding a workaround based on the other posting, but I'd be curious to see this approach through.  Any thoughts on why it is dividing by 0?  Thanks

Comment: Try it now.  I added WHERE b1.AB >= 400.

Comment: It works!  Here is my final result after making a few changes.    SELECT
    p1.nameFirst as "First", 
    p1.nameLast as "Last",
    m1.s AS "SLUGGING"
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAX(
            (b1.H + (2 * b1.doubles) + (3 * b1.triples) + (4 * b1.HR)) / (b1.AB * 1.0)
        ) AS s
    FROM
        Batting b1
    WHERE
        b1.AB >= 400
) m1
JOIN
    Batting b
        ON 
                m1.s = (b.H + (2 * b.doubles) + (3 * b.triples) + (4 * b.HR)) / (b.AB * 1.0)
JOIN
    Players p1
        ON
            b.playerID = p1.playerID
WHERE
    b.AB >= 400;  Thanks again!